# Почему при задании вопроса у него моментально становится 2 показа?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы

Почему при задании вопроса у него моментально становится 2 показа? Допустим, 1 мой, а второй чей?

Comment: Робота =) а вообще это вопрос на мету.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков какого робота?

Comment: яндекса\гугла\любого иного поисковика\бота которы копипастит ответы на ***\ еще какого либо бота который просматриватет все вопросы.... недавно вон ребята раскопали бота который на пастбин копировал некоторые вопросы

Comment: Самое интересное, что вопрос задает субъект у которого это единственный вопрос...

Comment: @Air Это не субъект, это участник. А вопрос конечно интересный, откуда участник знает, сколько показов после задания  вопроса, если это собственно говоря первый вопрос.

Comment: На самом деле, не всегда. У меня часто по минуте держался 1 показ. Это вполне может быть что у кого-то автоматически открывается вопрос.

Comment: @0xdb, вот и я об этом

Comment: @Air Вполне может быть, что у него есть друг, от которого он все это узнал. Или новый аккаунт.

Comment: Один - твой собственный.

Answer (score 2):

Видимо, так получилось. Чем больше популярность ресурса, тем больше шансов получить число просмотров >1 сразу при задании вопроса. На SO в последнее время я не обращал внимания на этот показатель, но вот на MSE довольно часто получал именно единицу (и не помню других значений), то есть никто кроме меня (задающего вопрос) еще не обращался к странице вопроса.

Здесь, кстати, есть некая [неконсистентность с количеством просмотров профиля участника](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291588/339911). Попробуйте задать вопрос на каком-нибудь менее популярном сайте или на том же ruSO в ночное время по Москве, когда активность участников не достаточно высока.

---

Вообще, как уже заметили в комментариях, несколько странно видеть такой вопрос от участника, у которого нет других вопросов. Вероятно, вы задавали вопросы с другого аккаунта, в таком случае ваши учётные записи скоро объединят (ждите Grundy). Хотя может статься, что имеются и удалённые вопросы, но эту часть могут прояснить модераторы, хотя через [инструменты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=today) ничего подобного не видно.

Comment: _Хотя может статься, что имеются и удалённые вопросы_ это более вероятно :-) но и клонов исключать нельзя :):):)